# Logo resize - mobile version

Tags: css, wordpress, image, mobile, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to change the size of logo on my site ([www.skyrox.pl](http://www.skyrox.pl)) on mobile versions only.

I'm trying with this code, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
@media (max-width: 360px) {
    .header-main .logo {
        max-width: 50%;
        max-height: auto;
    }
}
```

Adding an additional CSS in WP Customize utility.

Comment: 360px is rather the lower end of mobile screen widths. Are you sure the one you are testing with, is that narrow? _"Adding an additional CSS in WP Customize utility."_ - is this supposed to be "live" already on the site you linked to? I can see `@media (min-width:992px) { .logo img { width: 125px; }}` apply at an appropriate width. The media query you mentioned, I can't find in the `style` element where your custom CSS gets output.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Target the img tag when applying CSS and increase mobile view width:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .header-main .logo img {
    max-width: 50%;
    max-height: 50px; /* Change as per needed */
 }
}
```

if still not working then try using !important:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .header-main .logo img {
    max-width: 50% !important;
    max-height: 50px; /* Change as per needed */
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! the !important worked perfectly! :)

Comment: Do you have a clue, how to decrease height of a blue element at the top, just above the logo? It seemd too large for me. Thank you very much, I wouldn't think that !important would work!

Comment: Try this. If not applying, Try !important @MateuszMajcher
    .header-topbar {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}